# Pass an JFrame to new created Class to receive logdata from the new class

Tags: java, swing

Its really hard for me to find on google what i am specially looking for or even explaining it correctly without knowing any special words, sry. I am working on my first SocketServer and want to expand it with a GUI. the first step i want to try is to create a simple logwindow for the server activity. i have a JFrame and can pass text to it.

```
public class Logger {

    private JFrame frame;    
    private JTextArea tArea;    
    private JScrollPane jsp;    
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
    File file = new File("C://");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String logTitle = new String(args[0]);

        new Logger(logTitle);

    }

    public Logger(String logTitle) {

        init(logTitle);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        //logToLogger(); // function to append logdata to textarea

    }

    public void logToLogger(String logText) {

        tArea.append(logText.toString());

        tArea.setCaretPosition(tArea.getDocument().getLength());

    }

    private void init(String logTitle) {

        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.setTitle(logTitle);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        tArea = new JTextArea();

        jsp = new JScrollPane(tArea);

        frame.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

i also have a main class for starting my server. when starting the mainclass, a logger should be initiated and then i will pass it to a new started Thread.

my mainclass

> I WANT TO PASS THE LOGGER TO THE MYTHREAD CLASS ON THE LINE WHERE I WROTE THE INLINE COMMENT

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer port = new Integer(args[0]);

        String logTitle = new String(args[1]);

        Logger log = new Logger(logTitle);

        MyThread t = new MyThread(port, log); // thats the part i cant handle

        log.logToLogger("Started on port " + port);

    }

}
```

and here is how i would start a thread

```
public class MyThread {

    public static void main(int port, Logger log) {

        log.logToLogger(port + "logged from MyThread");

    }

}
```

Comment: You've posted some statements about what you're doing and some code, but no question. Please tell us, what is your specific answerable question?

Comment: sorry i wrote it as an inline comment in mainclass. i wrote MyThread t = new MyThread(port, log); (log should be the logger object) and in MyThread i wrote log.logToLogger(port + "logged from MyThread"); my question is why the logger couldnt log data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't written anything that takes data in from a socket. You just need to pass the `Logger` object to the `MyThread` constructor, and call `log.logToLogger(receivedText);` from `MyThread`.

Your code should look like:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private Logger log;
    private ServerSocket socket;
    public MyThread(int port, Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
        log.logToLogger("SocketServer opened on port "+port);
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.logToLogger(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Socket server;
            try {
                server = socket.accept();
                log.logToLogger("Connection from"+server.getRemoteSocketAddress()); 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
                log.logToLogger("Received:"+reader.readLine());
                server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.logToLogger(e.getMessage());
            }


        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer port = new Integer(args[0]);
    String logTitle = new String(args[1]);
    Logger log = new Logger(logTitle);
    MyThread t = new MyThread(port, log);
    (new Thread(t)).start();
}
```

Socket code is adapted from here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Java/tutorial/tcp_socket_server_client.php

From cmd prompt on windows, run `telnet 127.0.0.1 1234` and type your message, it should come up in the `JFrame` assuming you run the app on port 1234.

You should probably extend the `run()` method to be more robust than just closing on line being received.

Comment: i wrote MyThread t = new MyThread(port, log); (log should be the logger object) and in MyThread i wrote log.logToLogger(port + "logged from MyThread"); isnt that right?

Comment: You need to change your `public static void main(int port, Logger log)` method to be `public MyThread(int port, Logger log)`.

Comment: thank you, please write it as an answer, it solved my problem and i want to accept it :D youre great, dude

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it seems to me that your entry point is ambiguous among the several classes... You may wanna start by renaming/modifying the 'main' methods in everything except your actual main class where you want it to enter. As it stands you currently have several acceptable entry points to your program from the looks of things. In particular, the 'main' method in your `Logger` class will never get called if your code executes the way you want it to, so you're gonna have to move that code elsewhere, perhaps to the constructor or something.

Also, `init` is called when running your java program as an applet, whereas `public static void main(String[] args)` is called when running as a standalone java application. However, *both methods will not run at the beginning of the same program.* In your `Logger` class you should move the code in `init` to an appropriate place in your constructor.

Jonno_FTW also has a good point about passing Logger as a parameter to constructor as well. You will also need to extend the `Thread` class or implement `Runnable` if you want to use MyThread as a thread (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). After that you will be able to actually start the thread using `MyThread.start()`.